# Heading tag overflowing column instead of resizing container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a simple looking calendar that just displays two weeks with time blocks. I created a template but I'm having an issue with the time block text displaying outside it's container.

[image: Here's what's happening.]

Here's the source html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 80%; margin:auto;">
      <div id="react-calendar">
        <div class="row calendar-container">
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Sunday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/31</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/7</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Monday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/30</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/6</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Tuesday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/29</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/5</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Wednesday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/28</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/4</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Thursday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/27</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/3</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Friday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/26</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/2</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col calendar-day m-1 p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Saturday</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row calendar-outterblock">
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>10/25</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                <h4>11/1</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>1:30-2:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                  <div class="col calendar-innerblock">
                    <h5>2:30-3:30pm</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the styling

```
.calendar-container{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.calendar-day{
    background-color: #222;
    border-radius: 4%;
}
.calendar-outterblock{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10%;
}
.calendar-innerblock{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    border-color: #888;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */
 html,
 body {
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #333;
 }
 
 body {
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 }
```

Thanks in advance! Also, I don't mind any comments related to suggestions on how to improve the look.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using ? With `bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` it looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Using `width: max-content;` and `min-width: max-content` did the trick.

```
.calendar-container{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.calendar-day{
    background-color: #222;
    border-radius: 4%;
    width: max-content;
}
.calendar-outterblock{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10%;
    width: max-content;
}
.calendar-innerblock{
    display: flex;
    border-color: #888;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: max-content;
    padding: 5%;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */
 html,
 body {
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #333;
 }
 
 body {
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 }
```